# Target multiple classes in JS string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to target two classes in the same JS snippet. I know 0 about JS. Is there an easy way to try and get at two classes with one JS effect? It seems to break when I use comma delimiters.

trigger-s-overlay & trigger-a-overlay

My JS:

```
/* Search */
(function() {
  var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-s-overlay' ),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.s-overlay' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
      'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
      'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
      'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

  function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
      classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
      classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
      var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
        if( support.transitions ) {
          if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
          this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
      };
      if( support.transitions ) {
        overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
      }
      else {
        onEndTransitionFn();
      }
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
      classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
    }
  }

  triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
  closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

My HTML:

```
<a id="trigger-s-overlay" class="global_btn icon_btn"><span class="icon-search"></span></a>

<div class="s-overlay overlay-scale search_overlay">
   content
</div>
```

&

```
<a id="trigger-a-overlay" class="global_btn icon_btn"><span class="icon-search"></span></a>

<div class="a-overlay overlay-scale">
    content
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you change the line getting the **trigger button**? Is it that you (now) have multiple trigger buttons?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by *"...get at two classes with one JS effect..."* If you've changed things so that you have multiple buttons, more of that code will need to change than just how you select the elements, because the code currently assumes just *one* of each of the elements (one trigger button, one overlay, one close button).

Comment: Added some html to hopefully give a little more clarity

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` returns one element only. It cannot return multiple elements.

There are other related functions that can return an array of elements, like `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByName`. Maybe they can help you solving your needs. But note that some of them may not work in every browser.

If you have to interact with the DOM often, [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a library that can help you with this. It makes interacting with the DOM quite easy and has lots of functionality and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two sets of elements that relate to one another, and the only difference is `s` rather than `a` in the `id` of the trigger button and the class of the overlay.

You can move your code into a function, pass the function a type (`s` or `a`), and have it use that type when setting things up. Something along these lines (see comments, you'll have to scroll right for a couple of them):

```
(function() {
  // Added these:
  setup("s");
  setup("a");

  // Added the function wrapper
  function setup(type) {
      var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-' + type + '-overlay' ), // <== Changed
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.' + type + '-overlay' ),            // <== Changed
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
          'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
          'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
          'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
          'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
          'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

      function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
          classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
          classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
          var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
              if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
              this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
          };
          if( support.transitions ) {
            overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
          }
          else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
          }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
          classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        }
      }

      triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
      closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
  }
})();
```

Comment: @EdVinicombe: Not immediately seeing any reason for that in the code or the markup in the question, I'm afraid some debugging will be required. :-) Fortunately, modern browsers have powerful debuggers ("dev tools").

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of nullsetup @ search_overlay.js:10(anonymous function) @ search_overlay.js:3(anonymous function) @ search_overlay.js:47

Comment: @EdVinicombe: Well, as I have no way to know what line 47 is, there's not a lot I can help with. Again, use the debugger in your browser. But that's telling you, most likely, that either `overlay` or `closeBttn` is `null` because the thing that would have gotten them didn't find them.

Comment: Sorry T.J - all new to this. The error i'm getting is

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null on line 10

line 10 = closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );

Comment: @EdVinicombe: That means that the line `overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.' + type + '-overlay' )` failed to find the element (it would be looking for `div.a-overlay`), so `overlay` is `null`. There's a `div.a-overlay` in the HTML in your question, but apparently not in your real page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88019/discussion-between-ed-vinicombe-and-t-j-crowder).